# Bootstrap 4 dropdown menu appears behind other elements

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I´m having problems with `bootstrap 4 dropdown menu`, if there is enough space and the dropdown is opened from bottom to top all menu appears fine, but if the menu is opened from top to bottom some `menu items` do appear behind the other divs. How can I fix that and why it happens only in a certain case? I tried with position relative and z-index but it doesn´t work.

> **Update**: @ZimSystem answer is fine, but it didn´t fix my problem, so I have updated my code to faithfully reproduce the issue I was facing.

Here is the simplified code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container').hover(function() {
        if (!$(this).find('.card').hasClass('flipped')) {
            $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped')
        }
        $(this).find('.card').addClass('hovered');
    }, function() {
        var val = $(this).find('.card');
        $(this).find('.card').removeClass('hovered');
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (!val.hasClass('hovered')) {
                val.removeClass('flipped')
            }
        }, 1000);
    });

});
```

```css
.dropdown{
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-top: 30% !important;
}
.dropdown a{
    width: 100% !important;
}
.dropdown-item{
    color: black !important;
}
.dropdown-menu{
    height: auto !important;
}

.container {
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3% 2.25% 0 2.25%;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}


.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
  -moz-transform-origin: right center;
  -o-transform-origin: right center;
  transform-origin: right center;
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  -moz-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  -o-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
}

.card div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card .front {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="main"><br>

<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="test">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink1">
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 9</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>

<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="test">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink2">
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 9</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>


<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="test">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink3">
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 9</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>


<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="test">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink4" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink4">
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 9</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>



<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="test">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink5" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink5">
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 9</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>



<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="test">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink6" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink6">
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 9</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>

<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="test">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink7" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink7">
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 9</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>

<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="test">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink8" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink8">
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 9</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>

</div>
```

Comment: I think, you can't do this without js.
Add class `big-z-index` whenever dropdown has class show

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Updated answer** (based on bounty request)

The problem is that the `transform-style: preserve-3d;` on the `.card` is **breaking the z-order** on the dropdown. When `popper.js` dynamically positions the dropdown, it adds `translate3d(x,x,0)` CSS to the dropdown.

Since the z-order is set to 0, the dropdown is hidden by all the other cards which have `transform-style: preserve-3d;` used for the flip animation. In order for the `dropdown-menu` to have proper `z-order` it must also be position with `translate3d`...

```
.dropdown {
   margin-top: 30%;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
   transform: translate3d(0,0,10px) !important;
}

.dropdown-menu{
    height: auto !important;
    position: relative !important;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,10px) !important;
}
```

Also, z-order won't work using `translate3d` unless the parent elements *also* have `transform-style: preserve-3d;`. So, in this case `transform-style: preserve-3d;` must be added to *all* the parent elements (`#main`, `.container`, `.back`, `.test`, and `.dropdown`)..

[Working **Demo** on Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/NUW060x6VT)

---

**Original answer**

The `z-index: 99999 !important;` on all `.dropdown` causes the lower row to overlay the dropdown of the upper row. Remove the `z-index`...

```
.dropdown{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30%;
}
```

Positioning of the dropdown is now controlled by `popper.js` which does some unexpected things. Try using **`data-flip="false"`** to prevent the dropdown from overlaying it's own button.

https://www.codeply.com/go/R0ePzWnvPC

```css
.test{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 3% 2.25% 0 2.25%;
    float: left;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 800;
}
.dropdown{
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-top: 30% !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="test">
   <div class="dropdown">
      <a title="Tu Voto" data-flip="false" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink2">
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
   <div class="dropdown">
      <a title="Tu Voto" data-flip="false" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink2">
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
   <div class="dropdown">
      <a title="Tu Voto" data-flip="false" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink2">
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
   <div class="dropdown">
      <a title="Tu Voto" data-flip="false" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink2">
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


<div class="test">
   <div class="dropdown">
      <a title="Tu Voto" data-flip="false" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink2">
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


<div class="test">
   <div class="dropdown">
      <a title="Tu Voto" data-flip="false" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink2">
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 9</span></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


<div class="test">
   <div class="dropdown">
      <a title="Tu Voto" data-flip="false" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink2">
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
   <div class="dropdown">
      <a title="Tu Voto" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink2">
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It cant be done with perspective and position? Is part of a more complex structure.

Comment: Im using flip cards, my dropdown menu is in the back of the flip card: https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html. Thats why Im using perspective. I hope this is enough information, if it isnt, I will need to get ready a more complex example that will take time.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what the issue is then. I added `perspective: 800` to my demo and it works fine. I had a typo in the previous comment.. it should be `perspective: 800`

Comment: Its fine but It doesnt look properly in Firefox.

Comment: FF also needs `transform: translate3d(0,0,10px) !important;` on the `.dropdown`. Updated: https://www.codeply.com/go/NUW060x6VT

Comment: This completly screws up the button. The height of the button becomes the height of the menu.

Answer (score 1):

It is kinda hack, I have wrapped all section in a div with `float-left` class and change the float of `.container` to right.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container').hover(function() {
        if (!$(this).find('.card').hasClass('flipped')) {
            $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped')
        }
        $(this).find('.card').addClass('hovered');
    }, function() {
        var val = $(this).find('.card');
        $(this).find('.card').removeClass('hovered');
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (!val.hasClass('hovered')) {
                val.removeClass('flipped')
            }
        }, 1000);
    });

});
```

```css
.dropdown{
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-top: 30% !important;
}
.dropdown a{
    width: 100% !important;
}
.dropdown-item{
    color: black !important;
}
.dropdown-menu{
    height: auto !important;
}

.container {
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3% 2.25% 0 2.25%;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}


.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
  -moz-transform-origin: right center;
  -o-transform-origin: right center;
  transform-origin: right center;
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  -moz-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  -o-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
}

.card div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card .front {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="main"><br>
<div class="float-left">
<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="test">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink1">
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 9</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>

<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="test">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink2">
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 9</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>


<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="test">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink3">
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 9</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>


<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="test">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink4" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink4">
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 9</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>



<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="test">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink5" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink5">
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 9</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>



<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="test">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink6" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink6">
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 9</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>

<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="test">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink7" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink7">
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 9</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>

<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="test">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink8" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Test Dropdown
      </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink8">
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 1</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 2</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 3</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 4</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 5</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 6</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 7</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 8</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item"><span>Test Dropdown 9</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but the other solutions here and in other posts didn't work for me. I solved it using jQuery:

```
// when dropdown toggle button is clicked
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {

    // reset the z-indexes for the cards
    $(".card").each(function() {
        $(this).css('z-index', 1)
    });

    // then set the z-index for the .dropdown-toggle's closest .card ancestor
    $(this).closest('.card').css('z-index', 2);
});
```

You can reset the z-index for the .cards however you like. I only had two .cards on the page, so figured this was an easy way to do it.

Edit:
Here's another way to do it if you have a sticky footer that gets in the way :)

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.dropdown', function() {
            $open_menu = $(document).find('.dropdown-menu.show');
            $open_menu.closest('.card').css("z-index", "500");
        });
$(document).on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
            $open_menu = $(document).find('.dropdown-menu.show');
            $open_menu.closest('.card').css("z-index", "1");
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also check for overflow css property for parent element. In my case using BS4, I have updated overflow property for '.card' parent element to 'visible' from 'hidden'.

```
.card { overflow: visible; }
```